# Multiple instances - NG file upload Danial Farid ver 10

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload, ng-file-upload

I've looked at questions posted under this first tag but I could not find anything that matches what I am trying to do.

Is there a way to create multiple instances of the uploader in the same page?

I have this chunk that has been working well

```
<div
      class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-outline offset-sm-2 col-sm-8" id="fileSelectButton" name="fileUpload"
      ng-show="canSelect && !isProcessing && fileReaderSupported && !partialFiles.length"
      ng-id="odsFileSelect" tabindex="0"
      ngf-accept="selectedUploadType.expected_file_type"
      ng-model="selectedFiles" ngf-keep="'distinct'"
      ngf-select="setBannerStatus('isProcessing'); onFileSelect(selectedFiles); "
      ngf-multiple="true"
>
                        Click to upload {{ selectedUploadType.display_name }} files
                    </div>
```

Then I added this piece couple of lines below

```
<div
    class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-outline offset-sm-2 col-sm-8" 
    id="partialSelectButton" name="partialUpload"
    ng-show="canSelect && !isProcessing && fileReaderSupported"
    ng-id="odsPartialSelect" tabindex="0"
    ngf-accept="selectedUploadType.expected_file_type"
    ng-model="partialFiles" ngf-keep="'distinct'"
    ngf-select="onPartialSelect(partialFiles); "
    ngf-multiple="true"
 >
                                                            Click to add or replace files
                                                        </div>
```

even though the function fires on the second one, the model object is empty. It does not show the selected files

I'd really appreciate some help, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Sorry about the post. My code was not working because the second one was under an if render which was false at the beginning. I know the issue now, ty